# Unique constraint in XML / XSD

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm having a hard time trying to create validation for my xml.
This is my Schema.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- Schema namespace -->
<xs:schema
    targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/myschema/unique"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    xmlns="http://tempuri.org/myschema/unique"
    xmlns:mstns="http://tempuri.org/myschema/unique"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <!-- Root element -->
  <xs:element name="schedule">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>

        <!-- Student element -->
        <xs:element name="student">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="studentName" use="required"/>
            <xs:attribute name="studentId" type="xs:integer" use="required"/>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <!-- School element -->
        <xs:element name="school">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="0"/>
              <xs:element name="term"/>
              <xs:element name="program" minOccurs="0"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

        <!-- Weekdays element - uses clasTemplate -->
        <xs:element name="weekdays">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="day" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5" type="dayTemplate"/>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>

      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

    <!-- Set unique week day -->
    <xs:unique name="uniqWeekday">
      <xs:selector xpath="*/mstns:day"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@weekday"/>
    </xs:unique>

    <!--Set unique week day--> 
    <xs:unique name="uniqHourofclass">
      <xs:selector xpath="*/mstns:class"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@classHour"/>
    </xs:unique>

  </xs:element>

  <!-- ******************* Templates ******************* -->

  <!-- Day Template -->
  <xs:complexType name="dayTemplate">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="class" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="13" type="classTemplate"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="weekday" type="weekdayOptions" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- Class Template -->
  <xs:complexType name="classTemplate">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="courseCode" type="xs:string"/>
      <xs:element name="classRoom" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="classHour" type="hourofclassOptions" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <!-- ******************* Options ******************* -->

  <!-- Hour-of-class Options -->
  <xs:simpleType name="hourofclassOptions">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:unsignedInt">
      <xs:pattern value="(800|900|1[0-9][0]{2}|2000)"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

  <!-- Week Day Options -->
  <xs:simpleType name="weekdayOptions">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Monday"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Tuesday"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Wednesday"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Thursday"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Friday"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

And this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<schedule
          xmlns="http://tempuri.org/myschema/unique"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/myschema/unique Schema.xsd">

  <student studentName="Name" studentId="123456"></student>
  <school>
    <name>University</name>
    <term>2018</term>
    <program>CPA</program>
  </school>
  <weekdays>
    <day weekday="Monday"></day>
    <day weekday="Tuesday">
      <class classHour="1500">
        <courseCode>ABC-123</courseCode>
        <classRoom>A2020</classRoom>
      </class>
      <class classHour="1500">
        <courseCode>EFG-456</courseCode>
        <classRoom>A2758</classRoom>
      </class>
    </day>
    <day weekday="Wednesday">
      <class classHour="1500">
        <courseCode>VBN-996</courseCode>
        <classRoom>R8595</classRoom>
      </class>
    <day weekday="Thursday"/>
    <day weekday="Friday"/>
  </weekdays>

</schedule>
```

---

I need to validate classHour inside class. I can't have same classHour inside same day, but I can have same classHour in different days.
I'm using namespaces.
How can I make this work? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to define that within a P, every Q should have a unique value for R, then define an `xs:unique` constraint in the definition of P, in which xs:selector selects Q from P, and xs:field selects R from Q.

Applying that to your situation, the constraint that within a `day` (P), every `class` (Q) should have a unique value for `hour` (R) therefore needs to be in the element declaration for `day`.

Comment: You mean move unique element uniqHourofclass to inside weekdays element?
This way the constraint is identified, however that also happens between days.
Is there a way to limit this constraint to now allow same classHour within same day?

Comment: Sorry about that. What I need is this: I can't have class elements with same classHour attributes inside same day, but I might have class elements with same classHour attribute in different days. Like my xml sample: I can't have those 2 class elements on Tuesday (same classHour - 1500), but I might have one class element with classHour = 1500 on Tuesday and another class element with classHour = 1500 on Wednesday.

Comment: Then your constraint applies within a day and belongs in the element declaration for a day, as I said.

Comment: I did what I think I understood, which was put unique constraint uniqHourofclass inside day element. It didn't work fully. I have a constraint for all class elements, not only those inside that specific day that class element is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<!-- Root element -->
<xs:element name="schedule">
    ...
    <!-- Weekdays element - uses clasTemplate -->
    <xs:element name="weekdays">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="day" minOccurs="5" maxOccurs="5"type="dayTemplate">
                    <!--Set unique week day-->
                    <xs:unique name="uniqHourofclass">
                        <xs:selector xpath="mstns:class" />
                        <xs:field xpath="@classHour" />
                    </xs:unique>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
    ...
</xs:element>
```

In this case, `<xs:unique>` constraint is under `<day>`, so in the same `<day>` the attribute `classHour` must be unique (but can be repeated in a different `<day>`).

What you were trying to do would affect everything is under `<schedule>`, as you defined like this:

```
<!-- Root element -->
<xs:element name="schedule">
    ...
    <!--Set unique week day--> 
    <xs:unique name="uniqHourofclass">
        <xs:selector xpath="mstns:weekdays/mstns:day/mstns:class"/>
        <xs:field xpath="@classHour"/>
    </xs:unique>

</xs:element>
```

So in that case, it would affect to all `classHour` under `<schedule>`, which means that even for different `<day>` the attribute `classHour` must be unique.